# Chrome performing Google search instead of loading page from local server when adding query string

Tags: google-chrome, localhost

Oh man this is driving me crazy. I'm trying to test some code that reads my url, but when I add a query string, Chrome is performing a google search instead of loading the page from my local server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Firefox loads it fine.

URL in question: http://0.0.0.0:8000/dist/?webmap=1cc8ef8a9d8f4a5d97695adc328d245b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://0.0.0.0:8000 is not valid. This only means that port 8000 is listening on all network interfaces. Try connecting to http://localhost:8000 instead.

In addition, lookup your internal IP address and connect to that address on port 8000.